# RDP slow unless monitor plugged in

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a computer (local network) that I use via remote desktop only. Yesterday, I think it installed Windows updates and rebooted itself. Immediately after that, RDP was very, very slow. It took about 4 seconds to respond to every click. It's basically unusable. System performance was fine; CPU, memory, and network all at nominal levels. Another reboot did nothing.

So I plugged a monitor into the machine so I could see what's going on, and instantly the RDP performance goes back to normal. I unplug the monitor and everything seems fine. But if I minimize/close the RDP, it goes back to being slow... until I plug the monitor back in.

It's a very strange, very frustrating issue. I don't have an extra port on my monitor to leave it plugged in, and I RDP to this computer on a /very/ regular basis. I need it to respond normally when I do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nowadays RDP can make use of an existing GPU in certain situations. If no monitor is connected the GPU may shut down so it can't be used for RDP. However the major question is more why your system uses the GPU für a default desktop. Do you enforce fancy 3D effectes via RDP or other software that shows graphical effectes? What happens if you manually enable/disable some of the performance settings in the RDP client?

Comment: I set it to modem 56k (so all options unchecked), high color (15-bit) and 1080p (I run 4k full-screen normally), and there's no difference.

I noticed in the task manager that is does appear to be using the GPU (It says GPU 0 - 3D) for some processes, including the desktop window manager, windows driver foundation, occassionally the system processes, and remote desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the graphics drivers seems to have done the trick. I'm guessing there was some incompatibility with the older graphics drivers and the Windows update.